Angular 17 AngularFireModule Not Provided in AppModule' When Executing FirestoreDataService Test Cases with Jasmine and Karma
jasmin-karma error image ,
import module image
import { ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { getFirestore, provideFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Query } from 'firebase-admin/firestore';
import { of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { FirestoreDataService } from './firebase-common-function.service';
import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Auth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
type SnapshotOptions = {
  serverTimestamps?: 'estimate' | 'previous' | 'none';
};

type FirestoreStreamOptions = {
  idField?: string;
} & SnapshotOptions;

fdescribe('FirestoreDataService', () => {
  let service: FirestoreDataService;
  let errorHandlerSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<ErrorHandler>;
  let angularFireStoreSpy: any;
  let auth: jasmine.SpyObj<Auth>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const authSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('Auth', ['currentUser']);
    errorHandlerSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ErrorHandler', ['handleError']);
    angularFireStoreSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('Firestore', [
      'collection',
      'doc',
      'getDoc',
    ]);
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
        provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
      ],
      providers: [
        FirestoreDataService,
        { provide: ErrorHandler, useValue: errorHandlerSpy },
        { provide: AngularFirestore, useValue: angularFireStoreSpy },
        { provide: Auth, useValue: authSpy },
      ],
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(FirestoreDataService);
    auth = TestBed.inject(Auth) as jasmine.SpyObj<Auth>;
    angularFireStoreSpy = TestBed.inject(
      AngularFirestore,
    ) as jasmine.SpyObj<AngularFirestore>;
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should return default options when no options are provided', () => {
    const result = service.getStreamOptions();
    expect(result).toEqual({ idField: 'id' });
  });

  it('should merge provided options without idField', () => {
    const options: FirestoreStreamOptions = { serverTimestamps: 'estimate' };
    const result = service.getStreamOptions(options);
    expect(result).toEqual({ idField: 'id', serverTimestamps: 'estimate' });
  });

  it('should merge provided options with idField', () => {
    const options: FirestoreStreamOptions = {
      idField: 'customId',
      serverTimestamps: 'estimate',
    };
    const result = service.getStreamOptions(options);
    expect(result).toEqual({
      idField: 'customId',
      serverTimestamps: 'estimate',
    });
  });

  it('should return collection stream as observable', (done) => {
    // Arrange
    const queryMock: any = {} as Query<any>;
    const mockData = [{ id: 1, name: 'Test' }];
    spyOn(service, 'getStreamOptions').and.returnValue({});
    angularFireStoreSpy.collection.and.returnValue(of(mockData));

    // Act
    const result$ = service.getCollectionStream(queryMock);

    // Assert
    result$.subscribe((data) => {
      expect(data).toEqual(mockData);
      done();
    });
  });

  it('should handle errors and throw them', () => {
    // Arrange
    const mockError = new Error('Test error');
    const queryMock: any = {} as Query<any>;
    spyOn(service, 'getStreamOptions').and.returnValue({});
    angularFireStoreSpy.collection.and.returnValue(throwError(() => mockError));

    // Act & Assert
    expect(() => {
      service.getCollectionStream(queryMock);
    }).toThrow(mockError);
  });
  describe('fetchDocs', () => {
    it('should return documents when getDocs is successful', (done) => {
      const mockQuery = {}; // Mock your query object here
      const mockDocs = { docs: [{ id: '1', data: () => ({ name: 'doc1' }) }] };

      spyOn(service, 'fetchDocs').and.callThrough();
      angularFireStoreSpy.collection.and.returnValue({
        get: jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(of(mockDocs)),
      } as any);

      service.fetchDocs(mockQuery).subscribe({
        next: (docs) => {
          expect(docs).toEqual(mockDocs);
          done();
        },
        error: done.fail,
      });

      expect(angularFireStoreSpy.collection).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockQuery);
      expect(service.fetchDocs).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockQuery);
    });

    it('should handle errors and rethrow them', (done) => {
      const mockQuery = {}; // Mock your query object here
      const mockError = new Error('Failed to get documents');

      spyOn(service, 'fetchDocs').and.callThrough();
      errorHandlerSpy.handleError.and.callFake((error) => {});
      angularFireStoreSpy.collection.and.returnValue({
        get: jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(throwError(mockError)),
      } as any);

      service.fetchDocs(mockQuery).subscribe({
        error: (error) => {
          expect(errorHandlerSpy.handleError).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockError);
          expect(error).toBe(mockError);
          done();
        },
      });

      expect(angularFireStoreSpy.collection).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockQuery);
      expect(service.fetchDocs).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockQuery);
    });
  });

  describe('fetchDoc', () => {
    it('should return document when getDoc is successful', (done) => {
      const mockQuery = 'docId'; // Mock your document ID or query here
      const mockDoc = { id: '1', data: () => ({ name: 'doc1' }) };

      spyOn(service, 'fetchDoc').and.callThrough();
      angularFireStoreSpy.doc.and.returnValue({
        get: jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(of(mockDoc)),
      } as any);

      service.fetchDoc(mockQuery).subscribe({
        next: (doc) => {
          expect(doc).toEqual(mockDoc);
          done();
        },
        error: done.fail,
      });

      expect(angularFireStoreSpy.doc).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockQuery);
      expect(service.fetchDoc).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockQuery);
    });

    it('should handle errors and rethrow them', (done) => {
      const mockQuery = 'docId'; // Mock your document ID or query here
      const mockError = new Error('Failed to get document');

      spyOn(service, 'fetchDoc').and.callThrough();
      errorHandlerSpy.handleError.and.callFake((error) => {});
      angularFireStoreSpy.doc.and.returnValue({
        get: jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(throwError(mockError)),
      } as any);

      service.fetchDoc(mockQuery).subscribe({
        error: (error) => {
          expect(errorHandlerSpy.handleError).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockError);
          expect(error).toBe(mockError);
          done();
        },
      });

      expect(angularFireStoreSpy.doc).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockQuery);
      expect(service.fetchDoc).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockQuery);
    });
  });
  describe('getDocStream', () => {
    it('should return document data when docData is successful', (done) => {
      const mockDocRef = {} as any;
      const mockData = { id: '1', name: 'Document 1' };

      spyOn(service, 'getDocStream').and.callThrough();
      angularFireStoreSpy.doc.and.returnValue({
        snapshotChanges: jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(of(mockData)),
      } as any);

      service.getDocStream(mockDocRef).subscribe({
        next: (data) => {
          expect(data).toEqual(mockData);
          done();
        },
        error: done.fail,
      });

      expect(angularFireStoreSpy.doc).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockDocRef.path);
      expect(service.getDocStream).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockDocRef);
    });

    it('should handle errors and rethrow them', (done) => {
      const mockDocRef = {
        path: 'mock/doc/path',
      } as any;
      const mockError = new Error('Failed to get document');

      spyOn(service, 'getDocStream').and.callThrough();
      errorHandlerSpy.handleError.and.callFake((error) => {});
      angularFireStoreSpy.doc.and.returnValue({
        snapshotChanges: jasmine
          .createSpy()
          .and.returnValue(throwError(mockError)),
      } as any);

      service.getDocStream(mockDocRef).subscribe({
        next: done.fail,
        error: (error) => {
          expect(errorHandlerSpy.handleError).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockError);
          expect(error).toBe(mockError);
          done();
        },
      });

      expect(angularFireStoreSpy.doc).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockDocRef.path);
      expect(service.getDocStream).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockDocRef);
    });
  });
});



Problem Details:
Error: Either AngularFireModule has not been provided in your AppModule (this can be done manually or implictly using
provideFirebaseApp) or you're calling an AngularFire method outside of an NgModule (which is not supported).
I am encountering an issue with AngularFireModule while testing FirestoreDataService in my Angular application with jasmin karma. The errors indicate that AngularFireModule has not been properly provided in my AppModule, or I am calling AngularFire methods outside of an NgModule context, which is not supported.
Specifically, the errors occur during tests related to fetching documents and handling errors within FirestoreDataService. Here are some of the errors I'm encountering:
fetchDoc method: Errors indicate AngularFireModule is not provided or methods are being called outside of NgModule.
getDocStream method: Similar errors suggesting AngularFireModule is missing or methods are incorrectly called.
Error Handling: Tests expecting error handling behavior are failing due to the AngularFireModule issue.
getDocStream returning data: Expected behavior to return document data fails due to missing AngularFireModule.
Collection stream as observable: Unable to obtain a collection stream due to AngularFireModule issue.
fetchDocs method: Errors persist with fetching multiple documents due to AngularFireModule misconfiguration.
These errors are crucial as they prevent proper testing and functioning of FirestoreDataService, which relies on AngularFire for Firestore interactions.
I have already ensured that AngularFireModule is imported correctly in my AppModule and that my tests are appropriately structured within NgModule contexts. Despite this, the issue persists.
I would appreciate any insights or guidance on resolving the AngularFireModule integration issue in my Angular application. Thank you.
I have attempted to integrate AngularFireModule into my Angular application by ensuring it is properly imported and configured in my AppModule. I expected that this setup would allow me to utilize AngularFire methods within my FirestoreDataService seamlessly, both in application code and during testing scenarios.
Actual Result:
Despite correctly importing AngularFireModule and structuring my tests within NgModule contexts, I encountered persistent errors during testing. Specifically, the tests related to fetching documents (fetchDoc and fetchDocs methods) and handling errors within FirestoreDataService failed consistently. The error messages consistently pointed to issues with AngularFireModule not being provided in my AppModule or incorrect usage of AngularFire methods outside of NgModule contexts.
This discrepancy between expected and actual behavior has hindered my ability to conduct effective testing and utilize AngularFire functionalities as intended within my application.
